# rbind changes values in column

Tags: r, random-forest

So, I'm trying to extract all the tree data from a `randomForest` object, and place it into a data frame. I'm pulling out one tree at a time, `cbind`ing it with the index of that tree, and attempting to `rbind` it all together. Here's my code. Should be easily reproducible.

```
# Do some setup, and train a basic random forest model

library(randomForest)
data(iris)

model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)

# Make a data frame containing all the tree data

output <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:model[['forest']][['ntree']]) {
  new_values <- getTree(model, i)
  new_values <- cbind(tree = rep(i, nrow(new_values)), new_values)

  output <- rbind(output, test_new, make.row.names = FALSE)

  # Added for debug purposes...
  new_values
  output
  break
}
```

So, when I look at new_values, after the first step, tree has a value of 1. But when I look at the data frame "output," tree has a value of 500. If I let this loop run through without the debug code, at the end of the entire loop, "tree" is equal to 500 for the entire dataset. I would expect tree to be an index from 1 to 500, obviously.

Clearly I'm doing something majorly wrong, or the `rbind` process is somehow changing the values in my data. What's going on here?

(I suppose I could re-write with `do.call` and `lapply` and see if that changes anything, but I still want to know the mechanics of why this isn't working for learning purposes.)

Comment: `test_new` should be `new_values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just exchanged `new_values` by `test_new` inside  `rbind`. I changed it and tried the code below and could obtain  data frame with all the tree data, numbered according to the tree:

```
# Do some setup, and train a basic random forest model

library(randomForest)
data(iris)

model <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)

# Make a data frame containing all the tree data

output <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:model[['forest']][['ntree']]) {
  new_values <- getTree(model, i)
  new_values <- cbind(tree = rep(i, nrow(new_values)), new_values)

  output <- rbind(output, new_values, make.row.names = FALSE)

}
```